# angularjs ng-repeat doesn't show the data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this problem on my web page:

```
 app.controller('MessageController',['$http',function($http){
        http.get("DataManage.php?metodo=GetMessage")
        .then(function(response){
        this.Message=response.data.records;
        });


         this.ShowMyMessage=function(){
            console.log("Message");
            }   
    }])
```

The Json is arriving correctly but if I want to display those values inside a div using ng-repeat nothing appears:

```
   <div class="card-content Blue-text" ng-controller='MessageController'>
            <li id="MessageBox" ng-repeat='msg in Message'>
                    <span>{{msg.Text}}</span></li>
             </li>
       </div>
```

I checked a lot of time the implementation but I can't find the reason why this is happening.

Comment: Message should not be capitalized by convention and there should be spaces around your ' = '. *unless it is in the function definition for parameters as `(code='good', starter={}) => { body of function }`. But the actual problem you have is that you need $scope.messages (note its plural because its an array) not this.Message (this refers to controller not the scope as used in the view html).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you were trying to use `controllerAs` pattern. In that case you have to bind all variables inside controller function context(`this`) which you already did. But you missed to define controller alias inside `ng-controller` directive `value` like `ng-controller="MessageController as vm"`.

**Markup**

```
<div class="card-content Blue-text" ng-controller="MessageController as vm">
    <li id="MessageBox" ng-repeat='msg in vm.Message'>
        <span>{{msg.Text}}</span></li>
    </li>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MessageController', ['$http', function($http) {
  var vm = this; //put this inside vm to avoid this related issue.
  $http.get("DataManage.php?metodo=GetMessage")
    .then(function(response) {
       vm.Message = response.data.records;
    }
  );

  vm.ShowMyMessage = function() {
    console.log("Message");
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Oh it was so easy I did it in every controller but not in this One, thanks!

Comment: You could aceept an answer now. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.message` to `$scope.message`

```
app.controller('MessageController',['$http',function($http,$scope){
$http.get("DataManage.php?metodo=GetMessage")
.then(function(response){
 $scope.Message=response.data.records;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the scope variable.

```
app.controller('MessageController',['$http','$scope',function($http,$scope){

    $http.get("DataManage.php?metodo=GetMessage")
.then(function(response){

 $scope.Message=response.data.records;


});



this.ShowMyMessage=function(){

        console.log("Message");

}
}]);
```